# Integratin FirstPersonController in ursina main menu

Tags: python, game-engine, ursina

I make a simple ground and firstpersoncontroller in ursina but problem arises when i try to integrate with menu style here is code for main menu

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
BUTTON_SIZE = (.25, .075)

class MainMenu(Entity):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.enabled = True

        self.play_button = Button('Play', scale=BUTTON_SIZE, on_click=self.play_func, y=0.3, parent=self)
        self.settings_button = Button('Settings', scale=BUTTON_SIZE, on_click=self.settings_func, y=0.2, parent=self)
        self.exit_button = Button('Exit', scale=BUTTON_SIZE, on_click=self.exit_func, y=0.1, parent=self)

    def exit_func(self):
        sys.exit()

    def settings_func(self):
        self.enabled = False
        game_scene.enabled = False
        settings_scene.enabled = True

    def play_func(self):
        self.enabled = False
        settings_scene.enabled = False
        game_scene.enabled = True


class SettingsMenu(Entity):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.enabled = False

        self.back_button = Button('Back', scale=BUTTON_SIZE, on_click=self.back_func, parent=self)

    def back_func(self):
        self.enabled = False
        game_scene.enabled = False
        main_menu_scene.enabled = True


class Game(Entity):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.enabled = False
        self.back_button = Button('>>Back<<', scale=BUTTON_SIZE, on_click=self.back_func, parent=self)
    def back_func(self):
        self.enabled = False
        main_menu_scene.enabled = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ursina()

    main_menu_scene = MainMenu(parent=camera.ui)
    settings_scene = SettingsMenu(parent=camera.ui)
    game_scene = Game(parent=camera.ui)

    app.run()
```

Above code runs perfectly problem arises when I add a ground and a fpp controller in Game class like

```
self.ground = Entity(model='plane', texture='brick', collider='plane', scale=20, y=-0.5,parent=self)
  self.player = FirstPersonController(position=(0, 1, 0), speed=5, collider='box',parent=self)
```

The main menu is rendered along game scene note that only ground and player is rendered not back button

I tried adding a new class that handles the ground and player , messing around parent of ground and player
How I integrate this simple mechanics in this app

when I remove the ground and keep on player the main menu is rendered along with first preson cursor